# Database code is not connecting in chat program using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
// MySQL database connection file
$SERVER = "127.0.0.1"; // MySQL SERVER
$USER = "root";         // MySQL USER
$PASSWORD = "admin";        // MySQL PASSWORD

$link = @mysql_connect($SERVER,$USER,$PASSWORD);
$db = mysql_select_db("website");

?>
```

This is a database connecting code for chat program but it not connecting,Can any one pls help me to correct this code?

Comment: Are you sure that your MySQL Server is running?

Answer (score 4):

Drop the `@` infront of `mysql_connect`, it's used to suppress error which you don't want.

Also you need to check the return value of `mysql_connect` which is there in `$link` and make sure that it is not `false` before you proceed and to a DB select. Calling the function `mysql_error` when an error occurs gives you the reason for the error.

```
$link = mysql_connect($SERVER,$USER,$PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```